# Merging on Pandas dataframe with frequency counts

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `(df1)` with student details like -

```
Student ID     Course Code       Mark
   1              C001            88  
   1              C002            71
   2              C003            67
   3              C002            92
   3              C001            66
   3              C004            70
   4              C004            65
```

and another dataframe `(df2)` that has

```
WR ID        K ID        Course Code
SP-RS-01     K001        C002, C004
SP-RS-01     K004        C002
SP-RS-02     K005
SP-RS-03     K004        C003, C004
SP-RS-03     K006        C001
```

Now, I need a dataframe that includes the KID and WR ID for each Student ID as per the courses taken by them. And possibly, mention the count (as a dictionary) if they've done it more than once. So, something like this maybe -

```
Student ID       Courses           KID              WR ID
  1             C001, C002        K006, K001, K004  SP-RS-03
  2             C003              K004              SP-RS-01, SP-RS-03
  3             C001, C002, C004  K001x2, K006      SP-RS-01, SP-RS-03, 
                                  K004x2
  4             C004              K004              SP-RS-01, SP-RS-03
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: One question should student 3 k id be K001x2, K006,K004x2?

Comment: I don't follow, `Student ID` `1` has courses `C001, C002` why is the `KID` just `K006`?

Comment: As mentioned, your expected output does not make sense. Please correct or explain further.

Comment: Edited. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
#first flatten values pslitted by ,
s = (df2.set_index(['WR ID','K ID'])['Course Code']
        .str.split(',\s+', expand=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
        .rename('Course Code')
        )
#print (s)

#aggregate list per Course Code
df2 = (df2.drop('Course Code', axis=1)
          .join(s, on=['WR ID','K ID'])
          .groupby('Course Code')
          .agg(list)
          .reset_index()
          )

print (df2)
  Course Code                 WR ID          K ID
0        C001            [SP-RS-03]        [K006]
1        C002  [SP-RS-01, SP-RS-01]  [K001, K004]
2        C003            [SP-RS-03]        [K004]
3        C004  [SP-RS-01, SP-RS-03]  [K001, K004]
```

---

```
from collections import Counter

#combination flattening nested lists, Counter and new format with counts
f = lambda x: ', '.join(f'{k}x{v}' if v > 1 else k 
                        for k, v in Counter([z for y in x for z in y]).items())
#merge together and aggregate again
df = (df1.merge(df2, on='Course Code', how='left')
         .groupby('Student ID')
         .agg({'Course Code':', '.join,
               'WR ID':f,
               'K ID':f})
         .reset_index()
      )
print (df)
   Student ID       Course Code                   WR ID                  K ID
0           1        C001, C002    SP-RS-03, SP-RS-01x2      K006, K001, K004
1           2              C003                SP-RS-03                  K004
2           3  C002, C001, C004  SP-RS-01x3, SP-RS-03x2  K001x2, K004x2, K006
3           4              C004      SP-RS-01, SP-RS-03            K001, K004
```

EDIT:

Problem is some missing values, solution is repalce them to empty lists:

```
from collections import Counter

#combination flattening nested lists, Counter and new format with counts
f = lambda x: ', '.join(f'{k}x{v}' if v > 1 else k 
                        for k, v in Counter([z for y in x for z in y]).items())

#merge together and aggregate again
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Course Code', how='left')
df[['WR ID','K ID']] = df[['WR ID','K ID']].applymap(lambda x: x if x==x else [])

df = (df.groupby('Student ID')
        .agg({'Course Code':', '.join,
               'WR ID':f,
               'K ID':f})
         .reset_index()
      )
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael. This gives me a `'float' object not iterable` error on the `f = lambda x ...` line.

Comment: @harry04 - Edited answer. Please check it.

Comment: It doesn't give me any error now, but the result is very different from yours. I only get `WR ID` and `K ID` for the 4th row `Student ID`. All others are blank.

Comment: The first part gives me the resultant `df`, where some rows for `K ID` are like `[nan, nan, K016, nan, K068]` because I don't have any values for them. The second part gives `df` where I am only getting `K ID` and `WR ID` values for 4th row.

Comment: and these values for `WR ID` and `K ID` look like `S x36, P x26, - x102, R x21, ...` and `K x37, 0 x94, 2 x5, ...`. Please help! :/

Comment: @harry04 Are data condidental? If not, is possible sent it to my email in my profile?

Comment: Sure I can send you that!